# how to link a href 3 location by order

Tags: html, hyperlink

```
<a href=/01.html>BUTTON</a>
```

I have one button and it's linked 01.html now.

I want to link another page(02.html, 03.html) in order to BUTTON.
is it possible?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. You want all links on the the same button? Or separate buttons?

Comment: links on the same button.

Comment: Do you want to change the href of this button on click on another button?

Comment: It's only one button.first click = 01.html, second click = 02.html

Comment: Well you can put a button on each page or do you want an option were they can skip button 1 and go straight to button 2?

Comment: What do you mean "in order to button"? that is really lousy english... What is the purpose of having many links in the same button? do you want to open several pages with one click? Now I have seen you second comment, but I'm not sure why would someone want something like that... anyway, Koki's answer does that

Answer (score 3):

Jquery solution, and working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dAGUh/2/)**

```
var countClick= 0;
(function () {
 $('#link').click(function () {
 countClick++;
 if (countClick == 1) {
  window.open("http://google.com", '_blank');
 }
 if (countClick == 2) {
  window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/", '_blank');
 }
 if (countClick == 3) {
 window.open("http://yahoo.com/", '_blank');
 }
});
})();
```

Comment: That is really cool I didn't know this was possible. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Sure it is possible, just not so sure about the utility of it... :S Nice code, though...